# Model class for a json

Tags: java, json, gson

I have checked many examples of how to create a Model class for a json which is having key value pair. But I'm having following type of json in which field name depends on values in json. Please have a look at below json -

```
   { "args" : 
    [{
    "name":"fullName",
    "value":"Vikram",
    "type":"String"
    },
    {
    "name":"userName",
    "value":"abc@gmail.com",
    "type":"String"
    }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please help me for how to create model class for this json?
For above json I expect my model class should be like below -

```
public class Model {

    private String userName;
    private String fullName;
...


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String name) {
        this.userName = name;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String value) {
        this.fullName = value;
    }
}
```

Is that possible or not?
I know how to create model class for a json like -

```
 { "args" : 
    [{
    "fullName":"Vikram",
    "userName":"abc@gmail.com"
    }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this site?  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: yes, I tried it but it was not giving me Model class as I was expecting.

Comment: Why not? For example, `username` and `fullname` are not keys in your first JSON example. It is for the second JSON, but you also need a Java class with the `args` key that stores a list of Model

Comment: I think it's not possible because the layout is not know at compile time. I mean compiler doesn't know what is the name of fields until unless it map those fields.

Comment: It's possible with Jackson. It just stores a Hashmap of all extra keys that it can't parse into the model

Comment: Excuse me. Do you want to say what @JornVernee has added in below comment?

Comment: I mean, that'll work, but if you use Jackson instead of Gson, you can get that feature without needing to copy or understand that code

Comment: Okay. I will try that with Jackson. Thanks.

Comment: The `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation (from the site linked above) is what I'm referring to

Answer (score 1):

Creating a model in the way you mentioned is not possible, because the layout is not know at compile time. (Java does not have type providers)

Perhaps a convenient way is to serialize into some dictionary, but save the type of the value:

```
class Model {
    private final Map<String, Value> fields = new HashMap<>();

    public Value getValue(String fieldName) {
        return fields.get(fieldName);
    }

    public static Model deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        Model ret = new Model();

        JsonArray args = json.getAsJsonObject() // Get 'args' array
            .get("args")
            .getAsJsonArray();

        for(JsonElement e : args) {
            JsonObject o = e.getAsJsonObject(); 
            ret.fields.put(
                o.get("name").getAsString(),
                new Value(o.get("type").getAsString(), o.get("value"))
            );
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

```
class Value {
    private final String type;
    private final JsonElement obj;

    public Value(String type, JsonElement obj) {
        this.type = type;
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getAsString() {
        return obj.getAsString();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can register this `deserialize` method as a type adapter:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(
        Model.class,
        (JsonDeserializer<Model>) Model::deserialize
    ).create();

String json = ...;

Model m = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);

System.out.println(m.getValue("fullName").getAsString()); // 'Vikram'
System.out.println(m.getValue("userName").getAsString()); // 'abc@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Thank you. It cleared my doubt. Okay I will try this approach. But it would be difficult for me to access this model class in my app. Let say I want to access username from this class then I will need to write m.getValue("fullName"). This is how I will need to change all occurrences for getUserName() type getter and setters.  But yes its true the layout is not know at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private String value;
    private String type;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

use this class. for storing the data. create

```
List<Model> list =new ArrayList<>();
```

**create object Model class set its value then add to list.**

Comment: But I expect my model class should be like - 

public class Model {

    private String userName;
    private String fullName;
...


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String name) {
        this.userName = name;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String value) {
        this.fullName = value;
    }
}

Comment: @VikramBhati slightly confusing what you actually want. can you please post single json example what exactly you want instead of two. Your sample json should contain all the parameter which you want to store

Comment: See what I want to say. I need a class(i.e. UserInfo ) which I will use in my app to access any fields like username, fullname. Right now I'm getting json response which I have shared above. I want to convert that type of json response to java object(userInfo object here

Comment: ). So It could be simpler for me - If response were like - {
    "fullName":"Vikram",
    "userName":"abc@gmail.com"
    } 

then I could convert it to model class public class Model { private String userName; private String fullName; ... public String getUserName() { return userName; } public void setUserName(String name) { this.userName = name; }...}

Comment: But the problem is json response is in {
    "name":"fullName",
    "value":"Vikram",
    "type":"String"
    },
    {
    "name":"userName",
    "value":"abc@gmail.com",
    "type":"String"
    } 

format. Now I am confused how to covert it to model class.